# how to keep attributes saved in html (no cookies - just local storage)

Tags: javascript, html, storage

I have a calendar, in which dates are clickable. Each click it changes colors (white default, red and green - looped).

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

function inArray(needle, haystack) {
    if (!needle || !haystack) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var notFound = -1;
        for (var i = 0, len = haystack.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (haystack[i] == needle) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return notFound;
    }
}

function colorToggle(el, colors) {
    if (!el) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var colors = colors || [
            'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
            'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
            'rgb(0, 0, 255)'],
            wGCS = window.getComputedStyle,
            curColor = wGCS(el, null).backgroundColor;
        var pos = inArray(curColor, colors);
        if (pos > -1 && pos < (colors.length - 1)) {
            el.style.backgroundColor = colors[inArray(curColor, colors) + 1];
        }
        else if (pos > -1 && pos == (colors.length - 1)) {
            el.style.backgroundColor = colors[0];
        }
    }
}

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button.colorToggle');

for (var i = 0, len = buttons.length; i < len; i++) {
    buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
    buttons[i].onclick = function() {
        colorToggle(this, ['rgb(255, 255, 255)','rgb(0, 255, 0)','rgb(255, 0, 0)']);
    };
}

</script>
```

[image: Agenda item]

Now, I would like to keep the colors after refresh/reopening the index.html page.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll first need to assign an `id` or a `data-` attribute to each element so that you can associated your stored color values with the elements to which they are assigned upon reloading the page. As an example let's use the ISO date for each cell as an identifier.

Each date cell in the calendar might look like this:

```
<button data-date="2015-09-01" class="colorToggle">1</button>
<button data-date="2015-09-02" class="colorToggle">2</button>
```

Then, in `colorToggle` you can persist the data to `localStorage` like so:

```
localStorage.setItem(el.getAttribute("data-date"), el.style.backgroundColor);
```

On page load you can reset the colors by first retrieving your nodes and then attempting to pull the color out of `localStorage` and assign the color back.

```
var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("[data-date]"));
nodes.forEach(function (node) {
  var date = node.getAttribute("data-date");
  var color = localStorage.getItem(date);
  if(color) {
    node.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
});
```

Just a final note that I highly recommend including a polyfill for the ES5 Array.prototype methods. This will give you access to `forEach` in the example above and allow you to replace `inArray` with `Array.prototype.indexOf`.